# Joining strings in a JArray with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

I have a JArray that looks like this:

[image]

I'm using the code below to get the intended result:  `6035940:8061090,6035940:8084337`.

Can I clean this up with Linq?  How?

```
public static string GiveClientCampaignParam(JArray myArray)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var arrayItem in myArray)
    {
        string clientId = arrayItem["ClientId"].ToString();
        string campaignId = arrayItem["CampaignId"].ToString();

        sb.Append(clientId + ":" + campaignId + ",");
    }
    sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Why are you removing the last *two* characters rather than just the last character? Note how your output ends with 808433 rather than 8084337...

Comment: @Jon Skeet You're right.  It should be the last chara, not last two.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [string.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select(v=vs.100).aspx) to project the JArray element to a string:

```
public static string GiveClientCampaignParam(JArray myArray)
{
    return string.Join(",", myArray.Select(j => $"{j["ClientId"]}:{["CampaignId"]}"));
}
```

Using [string.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) also means you don't need to subtract the additional comma from the end.

Comment: There's no need to call `ToString()` there... it will be done automatically by `string.Format`.

Answer (score 5):

This should work.

```
return string.Join(",", myArray.Select(a => a["ClientId"] + ":" + a["CampaignId"]));
```